# Enable external SSH traffic on selected workstations within my network

Tags: networking, ssh, openwrt

I have already enabled an external SSH connection (with public and private keys) to my router, however... I would also like to enable an ssh connection to one of my internal workstations (permanently @  192.168.1.3)

How would I enable remote access to this workstation from an external network? I dont see how port forwarding would work, because it can either route to the firewall router or to the workstation behind the router.

Please share some light on this for my simple mind. 
I plan to setup a WinSCP (or Putty) ssh connection when remotely accessing the two network devices.

ps. my router is running openWRT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct port forwarding port 22 doesn't help in this case.

A solution is to connect to your gateway device on a different port had have it forward the connection to port 22 on your internal host. You then need to use the `-p` option to specify the port e.g. if you forward port 2222 then

```
ssh -p 2222 you@yourgateway.device ...
```

You could also have your gateway device listen for it's connections on a non standard port and then have it forward port 22.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps, yes my router is already on a non standard port- i will simply forward port 22 traffic to my workstation!... thanks again!